# Is there any other way to see a program's behavior when an exception occurs beside `throw new`?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I am writing in C# a routine which reads lines from a text file, using the `File.ReadAllLines` function. The code goes like this:

```
private void ReadFromLibrary()
{
 string[] ReadBuffer = new string[] { };

 try
        {
            ReadBuffer = File.ReadAllLines("Library.txt");
        }

 catch (FileLoadException F)
        {
            MessageBoxButtons MB = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            MessageBoxIcon MI = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
            MessageBox.Show(F.Message, "Error!", MB, MI);
        }
}
```

I want to see how this function will behave an runtime, when the `FileLoadException` exception occurs. I don't think manually altering the state of my machine so this exception happens is a good idea and the only alternative I know is inserting `throw new FileLoadException` after reading from the file.

Is there any other alternative for obtaining the same result? I don't see anything wrong in using `throw new`, but I want to know if I can do it another way.

Comment: Give the class constructor a IFile interface argument. Then in a Unit Test on `ReadFromLibrary` mock the `File.ReadAllLines` method to throw a `FileLoadException` and pass the mocked IFile to the constructor before calling the `ReadFromLibrary` method.

Comment: Or simply change the `Library.txt` from hard-coded to a parameter...

Comment: @JeremyThompson well, if you want some rep, you can always answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeremy said,

> Give the class constructor a `IFile` interface argument. Then in a Unit
>   Test on `ReadFromLibrary` mock the `File.ReadAllLines` method to throw a
>   `FileLoadException` and pass the mocked `IFile` to the constructor before
>   calling the `ReadFromLibrary` method.